# Is the electric potential same everywhere in a shell where electrons revolve?

Tags: electrons, potential

The shell in which the electron revolves, is that an equipotential surface because the electron revolves with constant speed, so it means that there is no change in kinetic energy and hence no work is done in moving the electron which is in the case of equipotential surface

Comment: The electronic orbitals of an atom are described by quantum mechanics. We can not attribute a trajectory or a well-defined speed to the electrons in such theoretical framework. You can not make the statement that "the elctron revolves with constant speed" as a few of the words involved do not make sense for a quantum particle

Comment: But the potential at each point in a shell is constant

Comment: The shell model is somewhat outdated and doesn't hold much physical details, so it is hard to discuss the details of it while still making sense. But a single "electronic shell" can hold different atomic orbitals that have different energy levels. So I would say "no". But mostly I would say, "if you're committed to use the shell model, don't ask too much questions about its coherence" :p